# Android Listview - clickable items with youtube links?

Tags: android, listview, youtube

I've already created a listview, that has 40 names of songs, and a standard adapter for it. Do you have any idea about how I can make the items clickable with links?

Edit: Thank you all :)

Comment: Do you mean like when it clicks it opens something?

Answer (score 0):

If the order / items are static you can store the links as strings in an array and then access the array to get the corresponding string and navigate to it using an Intent.

Here is an example of an intent to a web address

```
String url = "http://www.youtube.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should use a onItemClickListener!

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

Then use this code in it!

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```